# Issues with water supply/faucets after frozen pipes

Tags: plumbing

We woke up to frozen pipes this morning. We cranked the heat and opened all the faucets.

Water started flowing first to our ½ bath and then shortly after that to the other faucets but only cold water and then it got strange.

If we turn on the ½ bath faucet the other faucets flow but only cold water. As soon as we turn it off all the other faucets turn off.

Why????

Added info:  The ½ bath is the first place the water comes into the house from the main water line at the street.  This is in the front of the house. We turned on the faucets in our master bath, upstairs bath and the kitchen sink.  Kitchen sink is the last and furthest from the main line.

Water starts to flow in the ½ bath sink (both cold and hot handle on runs through one spout - cold runs more).  After about 2-3 minutes water will flow in the master bath tub and sinks and then a minute or so after that the water in the kitchen sink will flow.  Upstairs just gurgles.

If we turn off the water in the ½ bath and leave the faucets open all over the rest of the house the water will stop flowing and never start until we turn on the faucet in the ½ bath again.

MORE:

Ok so with all the faucets open we turned the ½ bath to full cold and you are correct the other faucets stopped.  We tried with just the hot on in the ½ bath and nothing.  Put both back on and they all started again.

How would I find the non-return valve that is stuck.

Comment: If your water heater is gas, make sure the pilot hasn't gone out.

Comment: There's probably still some ice in the system. It's hard to say what else could cause this knowing  nothing about your plumbing. Please revise to add detail about layout, type, etc.

Comment: Does this half bath have a single temperature-controlled tap (faucet) rather than two distinct taps? Best guess is a non-return valve is stuck, allowing water through that control whilst it's open/on, then closing off when it's closed/off. So, basically returning the cold inlet to the rest of the hot line.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great comment, probably should be an answer. If the OP turned the 1/2 bath faucet to full cold and then the other faucets stopped flowing, that would confirm your hypothesis.

Comment: @ttsujin I agree and was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Added info: The ½ bath is 1st place water comes into house from main water line at street. We turned on faucets in master & upstairs bath & kitchen sink. Kitchen sink is the last & furthest from main line.

Water starts to flow in ½ bath-both cold & hot handle on runs through one spout-cold runs more.After about 2 minutes water flows in master bathtub & sink, then a minute or so later water in kitchen sink flows. Upstairs just gurgles.

If we turn off the water in ½ bath & leave faucets on in rest of house water will stop flowing & not start until we turn on faucet in ½ bath again.

Comment: @Tetsujin

Ok so with all the faucets open we turned the ½ bath to full cold and you are correct the other faucets stopped. We tried with just the hot on in the ½ bath and nothing. Put both back on and they all started again.

How would I find the non-return valve that is stuck.

Comment: I'd love to add an answer… but this was really just 'early diagnosis/triage' to find the cause - I don't actually know how you'd find it or fix it. Though I come from a family of plumbers, I'm not one, so a lot of my knowledge is theoretical rather than practical.